# How rm command free up disk space?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, rm

I'm trying to understand how `rm` command works and get this [one](https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/linux-tutorials/permanently-and-securely-delete-files-in-linux.html):

> The rm command removes the entry of specified file from indexing.
> Since file is removed, Linux marks the block where the file was stored
> as free and makes it available for new file. While storing a new file
> in disk, Linux uses indexing to find the free blocks. If a block is
> marked as free in indexing, it is used to store the new data
> regardless what it contains.
>
> From technical point of view, no, a deleted file persists in the disk until a new file or folder is stored at the same place where the file was stored.

As it said, how I get more free disk space each time using `rm` command?

Comment: The paragraph you've quoted says, "Since file is removed, Linux marks the block where the file was stored as free and makes it available for new file." That's effectively the answer to your question...blocks belonging to the file you've deleted are marked as free.

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial you quote is mainly referencing the purpose of the `shred` utility. (The article is not particularly well written.)

**On the `rm` command:** the system keeps a reference count on each file. It knows how many hard links there are to the file's inode, and how many processes currently have an open file descriptor for it.

One specific directory entry for the file will be removed by each valid `rm`. When there are no more links to the inode for the file, and there are no processes holding a valid file descriptor for it, the file system driver will return the inode, and all the data blocks used by the file, to the free list.

**On the `shred` command:** returning the file data blocks to the free list does not destroy the data in those blocks. They can still be retrieved by reading the disk as a block device, which can be a data security risk.

The `shred` command is used to over-write all the data blocks that were part of the file (with zeros or random numbers) to prevent the data being recovered. The blocks are then released to the free list. `shred` has several weaknesses noted in the man page. It does a bad job on journaling file systems and on SSD devices.